# How to change comma separated values in a single element to multiple columns and assign numeric coding

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many columns to transform into multiple columns in the data I have extracted from Google Drive file in R. The name of dataframe where the data is stored is **Data**

Now, lets start with the following column in the extracted data in R with header and top 4 values:

```
Data$Param1
-----------
Private Bus, Private Car, Public Bus
Private Car, Private Van, Public Bus
Private Car
Private Bus, Private Car
```

From above column we have four (4) set of values namely:

- Private Bus
- Private Car
- Private Van
- Public Bus

How can I transform the column **Data$Param1** into respective columns for each element of the set of 4 values I have mentioned above and within each column the values should be "0" if absent in Data$Param1 and "1" if present in Data$Param1.

Like this:

```
            Data$Param1              | Data$Param1_PrivateBus | Data$Param1_PrivateCar | Data$Param1_PrivateVan | Data$Param1_PublicBus |
Private Bus, Private Car, Public Bus |          1             |            1           |            0           |           1           |
Private Car, Private Van, Public Bus |          0             |            1           |            1           |           1           |
             Private Car             |          0             |            1           |            0           |           0           |
      Private Car, Private Bus       |          1             |            1           |            0           |           0           |
```

I have exactly 187 similar columns to transform having different set of values. Some column have set of 5 values while some has set of 6, 7, and 9 values.

I am using R ver 3.4.1.

Comment: Try `cSplit_e` from "splitstackshape".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dplyr, stringi and reshape2 will do all the work you need

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("stringi")
install.packages("reshape2")

library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(reshape2)

xx_df <- data.frame(Param1 = c("Private Bus,Private Car,Public Bus", "Private Car,Private Van,Public Bus", "Private Car", "Private Bus,Private Car")
          , stringsAsFactors = F)

cbind(xx_df, stringi::stri_split_fixed(xx_df$Param1, ",", simplify = T) ) %>% 
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars = "Param1", na.rm = T) %>% 
  mutate(variable = 1)  %>% filter(value != '') %>% 
  reshape2::dcast(Param1~value, value.var = "variable", fill = 0) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

result is

```
                              Param1 Private.Bus Private.Car Private.Van Public.Bus
1            Private Bus,Private Car           1           1           0          0
2 Private Bus,Private Car,Public Bus           1           1           0          1
3                        Private Car           0           1           0          0
4 Private Car,Private Van,Public Bus           0           1           1          1
```